# Loop Script for Nested Arrays - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

I'm trying to create a loop script for my app that checks if the array of users is full and if not, it puts in the user ID.

My JSON file is based on `MongoDB` and it has 24 entries (hours). Each entry has a `mins` array (see below)

I tried the following script, but it's supposed to check each array in a raw disregarding the `min` value.

```js
const hour = await db.Timer.findOne({hour: time[1]}) // finding an hour in the DB
const timer = await db.Timer.findOne({hour: time[1]}, { mins: {"$elemMatch": {min: time[2]}}}) // finding a minute
let maxUsers = 3
for(let i = 0; i < hour.mins[i].users.length; i++) {
    if(hour.mins[i].users.length < maxUsers){
      console.log(i)
    } 
}
```

`hour` and `timer` are arrays can be found by `time[1]` (hour) and `time[2]` (minute). This is what I should work with.

```js
// how the 'mins' array looks like
[
  {
    users: [ 432143, 543254, 6545423 ],
    min: 21
  },
  {
    users: [ 3421, 432143, 43213 ],
    min: 22
  },
  { users: [ 7735 ], min: 23 },
  { users: [], min: 20 }
]

// output for 'hour'
{
  hour: 15,
  mins: [
    { users: [Array], min: 21 },
    { users: [Array], min: 22 },
    { users: [Array], min: 23 },
    { users: [], min: 20 }
  ]
}

// output for 'timer'
{
  mins: [ { users: [Array], min: 21 } ]
}
```

Please suggest how to check the arrays by minute.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks. I'm a newbie, so maybe I'm wrong here.
Could you please help me here? I'd be grateful!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't use MongoDB. Also, I don't think it's clear from the above what the structure of `hour` and `timer` is...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I updated the post, please check it
Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

For those who're interested in the solution.

Here is how I solved my problem:

```js
let mitunes = hour.mins
      const guys = mitunes.filter(mitunes => mitunes.users.length < 3 && mitunes.min > time[2]);
      console.log(guys[0].min)
```